# Kafka CLI: Topic not present

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

I'm totally newbie in Kafka and following the tutorial by Stephane Maarek.
I'm trying to produce data for Kafka. My Zookeeper port is 2181 and has a topic: first-topic.

```
Topic: first-topic      TopicId: AiYAVfKyQxm3827NoYI8sw PartitionCount: 3     ReplicationFactor: 1    Configs:
        Topic: first-topic      Partition: 0    Leader: 0       Replicas: 0     Isr: 0
        Topic: first-topic      Partition: 1    Leader: 0       Replicas: 0     Isr: 0
        Topic: first-topic      Partition: 2    Leader: 0       Replicas: 0     Isr: 0
```

I'm trying to produce data by command:

```
kafka-console-producer --broker-list 120.0.0.1:9092 --topic first-topic
```

But I keep getting error:

```
[2021-08-15 14:36:27,204] WARN [Producer clientId=console-producer] Bootstrap broker 120.0.0.1:9092 (id: -1 rack: null) disconnected (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
[2021-08-15 14:36:48,373] WARN [Producer clientId=console-producer] Connection to node -1 (/120.0.0.1:9092) could not be established. Broker may not be available. (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
[2021-08-15 14:37:18,179] ERROR Error when sending message to topic first-topic with key: null, value: 1 bytes with error: (org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.ErrorLoggingCallback)
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Topic first-topic not present in metadata after 60000 ms.
[2021-08-15 14:39:15,333] WARN [Producer clientId=console-producer] Bootstrap broker 120.0.0.1:9092 (id: -1 rack: null) disconnected (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
```

I checked all posts but they don't make sense to me. Can anyone please suggest what I can do?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I just installed Kafka again. It's a workaround for now, but not the solution. Hopefully someone might tell the correct way.

Comment: You used 120.0.0.1, not 127.0.0.1, or better just localhost